# python : SQLAlchemy -> DB.query.all() return column names

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a minor issue with SQLAlchemy that i'm not able to solve. As of now, everytime i run a query such as `DB.query.all()` i get a result like this :

```
{'columnName': u'value1'}, 
{'columnName': u'value2'}, 
{'columnName': u'value3'}, 
{'columnName': u'value4'}
```

The `DB` in question contains only 1 column, and i get its name returned inside a `dict`. Is there any way to have a `list` instead ? something like :

`{'columnName': [u'value1', u'value2', u'value3', 3u'value4']}`

or even

`[u'value1', u'value2', u'value3', 3u'value4']`

?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact structure of what you get back from your SQLAlchemy query from your code (is it a list of dicts?)

> Is there any way to have a list instead?

You can pull the fields you want quite easily with a Python list comprehension:

```
>>> rows = [{'columnName': u'value1'}, 
{'columnName': u'value2'}, 
{'columnName': u'value3'}, 
{'columnName': u'value4'}]

>>> [row['columnName'] for row in rows]
[u'value1', u'value2', u'value3', u'value4']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use list comprehension on the result set, i.e. `[row.get('columnName') for row in DB.query.all()]`

Another option is you explicitly filter on fields i.e. `DB.query(DB.columnName).all()`, then I believe it should return a list of tuples instead of a list of dictionaries.